# linq query async/await review

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I'm upgrading a working linq pipeline to async and I'm struggling a bit with the synthaxe/logic (where to task.run, async/await, Tolist ...).
At the moment it won't compile as the last method returns an IEnumerable of Task  products instead of IEnumerable of products

here is the call :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetProducts(bool isLogged)
{
    return await _mapper.GetStripeProductsDto(isLogged, false);
}
```

one of the repos :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StripeProduct>> GetAllStripeProductsAsync()
{
    return (await _productService.ListAsync())
        .Where(x => x.Type == "good" && x.Active == true);
}
```

and where I build my dto and am struggling with :

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetStripeProductsDto(bool isLogged, bool isSubscriber)
    {
        var productList = (await _productRepo.GetAllStripeProductsAsync()).ToList();

        return await Task.Run(async () => 
                GetSkuOffers(productList)
                    .Concat(await GetSubsciptionOffers(productList))
                    .GroupBy(product => product.Name)
                    .Select(productGroup => new ProductDto
                    {
                        Name = productGroup.Key,
                        Id = productGroup.Select(product => product.Id).First(),
                        Description = productGroup.Select(product => product.Description).First(),
                        Image = productGroup.Select(product => product.Image).First(),
                        CurrentUserProfile = isSubscriber
                            ? OfferTypeEnum.Pro.ToString()
                            : isLogged
                                ? OfferTypeEnum.Registered.ToString()
                                : OfferTypeEnum.Basic.ToString(),
                        Prices = productGroup.Select(product => new
                        {
                            Offer = product.OfferType.ToString(),
                            Price = product.Price.ToString()
                        })
                        .ToDictionary(p => p.Offer, p => p.Price)
                    })
                    .ToList())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetSkuOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
    {
        return productList
            .SelectMany(sku => sku.Skus.Data, (product, sku) => new Product
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Id = product.Id,
                Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
                Description = product.Description,
                OfferType = sku.Id.Contains("Basic") ? OfferTypeEnum.Basic : OfferTypeEnum.Registered,
                Price = sku.Price
            });
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubsciptionOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
    {
        return 
            productList
            .Select(async product => new Product
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Id = product.Id,
                Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
                Description = product.Description,
                OfferType = OfferTypeEnum.Pro,
                Price = (await _planRepo.GetPlanByIdAsync(product.Metadata.First().Value)).Amount.GetValueOrDefault()
            });
    }
```

EDIT : compiling version, ToListAsync seems to work only for DBs, my repo makes calls to an api, so i gave up on that; I removed the Task.Run(...), and got rid of the IEnumerable of Task products in a probably nasty way

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetStripeProductsDto(bool isLogged, bool isSubscriber)
    {
        var productList = (await _productRepo.GetAllStripeProductsAsync()).ToList();
        var skuOffers = GetSkuOffers(productList);
        var subsciptionOffers = GetSubsciptionOffers(productList);

        return skuOffers
            .Concat(subsciptionOffers)
            .GroupBy(product => product.Name)
            .Select(productGroup => new ProductDto
            {
                Name = productGroup.Key,
                Id = productGroup.Select(product => product.Id).First(),
                Description = productGroup.Select(product => product.Description).First(),
                Image = productGroup.Select(product => product.Image).First(),
                CurrentUserProfile = isSubscriber
                    ? OfferTypeEnum.Pro.ToString()
                    : isLogged
                        ? OfferTypeEnum.Registered.ToString()
                        : OfferTypeEnum.Basic.ToString(),
                Prices = productGroup.Select(product => new
                {
                    Offer = product.OfferType.ToString(),
                    Price = product.Price.ToString()
                })
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Offer, p => p.Price)
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetSkuOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
    {
        return productList
            .SelectMany(sku => sku.Skus.Data, (product, sku) => new Product
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Id = product.Id,
                Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
                Description = product.Description,
                OfferType = sku.Id.Contains("Basic") ? OfferTypeEnum.Basic : OfferTypeEnum.Registered,
                Price = sku.Price
            });
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubsciptionOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
    {
        return productList
            .Select(product => new Product
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Id = product.Id,
                Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
                Description = product.Description,
                OfferType = OfferTypeEnum.Pro,
                //Price = _planRepo.GetPlanById(product.Metadata.First().Value).Amount.GetValueOrDefault()
                Price = GetSubscriptionPrice(product.Metadata.First().Value)
            }).ToList();
    }

    private int GetSubscriptionPrice(string str)
    {
        var plan = Task.Run(() => _planRepo.GetPlanByIdAsync(str)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return plan.Amount.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Why use `await Task.Run` when you can use `ToListAsync`. Also if you start using async/await, use it all the way. `GetSubsciptionOffers` should be async. You have to know how asynchronous programming works before refactoring code. It is much harder to find bugs if you don't know how it works.

Comment: Don't ever do this  `return await Task.Run(async () =>`. When there actually are  use natural Async methods because they actually run asynchronously and will be useful, if not use Task.FromResult for fake async stuff. Also you don't need to make a method async in fact it's good to avoid it if possible, so just return a regular Task if possible.

Comment: @FCin ToListAsync seems to be related to entity framework which I don't use, I am trying to learn async programming thats why I'm doing this ;)

Comment: @Filip Cordas why is it good to avoid making methods async? I kinda understood the opposite

Comment: @FilipCordas Overhead of using async/await instead of passing tasks is minimal. There is no reason why one should not use async/await in a chain of calls. Stephen Cleary has a blog post about it.

Comment: Apart from the problem mentioned, you have following other observations 1) `await _planRepo.GetPlanByIdAsync(product.Metadata.First().Value)` is called in loop. So every product the data will be fetched from DB --- which is not correct. 2) Instead of doing in memory filtering, you can do the filtering at source for code`await _productService.ListAsync())
        .Where(x => x.Type == "good" && x.Active == true)`. Change it to `await _productService
        .Where(x => x.Type == "good" && x.Active == true).ListAsync()`

Comment: @FCin _why one should not use async/await in a chain of calls_ I agree on that but there is an overhead when you just do await Task.FromResult(0)

Comment: @XavSc You misunderstand me not avoid always just when creating fake async methods there is no need to use them since they are only overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetProductsAsync(bool isLogged)
{
    return await _mapper.GetStripeProductsDto(isLogged, false);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<StripeProduct>> GetAllStripeProductsAsync()
{
    var list = await _productService.ListAsync();

    return await list.Where(x => x.Type == "good" && x.Active == true).ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetStripeProductsDtoAsync(bool isLogged, bool isSubscriber)
{
    // here you're making async call and when task is done, you are making .ToList() on results
    var productList = await _productRepo.GetAllStripeProductsAsync();

    // this will be executed when productList has results from database (task).
    // Because GetSkuOffers() method is sync you can execute this like below.
    var skuOffersResult = GetSkuOffers(productList);

    // get asynchronously subscription offers
    var getSubscriptionOffers = await GetSubsciptionOffers(productList);

    // this is done also synchronously so you don't need to use async/await statements
    skuOffersResult.Concat(getSubscriptionOffers)
                .GroupBy(product => product.Name)
                .Select(productGroup => new ProductDto
                {
                    Name = productGroup.Key,
                    Id = productGroup.Select(product => product.Id).First(),
                    Description = productGroup.Select(product => product.Description).First(),
                    Image = productGroup.Select(product => product.Image).First(),
                    CurrentUserProfile = isSubscriber
                        ? OfferTypeEnum.Pro.ToString()
                        : isLogged
                            ? OfferTypeEnum.Registered.ToString()
                            : OfferTypeEnum.Basic.ToString(),
                    Prices = productGroup.Select(product => new
                    {
                        Offer = product.OfferType.ToString(),
                        Price = product.Price.ToString()
                    })
                    .ToDictionary(p => p.Offer, p => p.Price)
                })
                .ToList());
}

private IEnumerable<Product> GetSkuOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
{
    return productList
        .SelectMany(sku => sku.Skus.Data, (product, sku) => new Product
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            Id = product.Id,
            Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
            Description = product.Description,
            OfferType = sku.Id.Contains("Basic") ? OfferTypeEnum.Basic : OfferTypeEnum.Registered,
            Price = sku.Price
        });
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetSubsciptionOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
{
    return
        productList
        .Select(async product => new Product
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            Id = product.Id,
            Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
            Description = product.Description,
            OfferType = OfferTypeEnum.Pro,
            Price = (await _planRepo.GetPlanByIdAsync(product.Metadata.First().Value)).Amount.GetValueOrDefault()
        });
}
```

Simple example how to use async/await:
Let say that you have service which uses repository to get product list - all made synchronously for now:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return _dbContext.Products.ToList();
    }
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public Service(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public List<Product> GetProductsFromDb()
    {
        return _repository.GetProducts();
    }
}
```

Now you want to change this code to make it work asynchronously:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Products.ToListAsync();
    }
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public Service(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsFromDbAsync()
    {
        return await _repository.GetProductsAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should remove the task.run. Mixing async and sync statements is not a problem? Also any idea why GetSubsciptionOffers returns a IEnum of Task of products instead of ienum of products?

Comment: I've edited my post, because there was some mistakes.

Comment: then shouldn't it return a Task<IEnumerable<Product>> ? why does it return a IEnumerable<Task<Product>> ?

Comment: I've created another simple example to make you understand it. If method makes something async (for example you use .ToListAsync() or executing another async method) you must change method to async Task and put await statement before executing async method.

Comment: yes thats my starting point I did that to the repos and all the way down. Ok, in your example, what happens if I use ToList() instead of ToListAsync() (no db involved here) is the method still executed asynchronously?

Comment: and how can I have GetSubsciptionOffers return a Task<IEnumerable<Product>> instead of IEnumerable<Task<Product>> as it does now ?

Comment: @XavSc you can't use async statement in non async method: private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubsciptionOffers

Comment: editted original post, probably not great but at least it compiles .. thanks